# Can we somehow predict the US Dollar vs IN Rupee rates for say next months with absolute certainty?

Tags: foreign-exchange

Background: I want to buy something for say 100 USD with 5% discount. Also, I want to pay minimum amount in INR. So, I have waited for 2  weeks now for the value to minimize but it started rising up again.

[image: USD vs INR]
source : http://www.exchange-rates.org/history/INR/USD/G/30

My question is: **Can one predict the Dollar vs Rupee rate for next 30 days with absolute 100% certainty**?

---

Disclaimer: This is my first question so please bear with me. Also, I have almost zero knowledge of economics.

Comment: It's difficult to predict things. Especially the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be very obvious that the answer is *NO*.

If anyone could predict it, he could easily get rich by just buying huge amounts of call/puts.

Comment: Okay, that is perfectly logical. Could you enlighten me on what parameters it is based and how is it decied?

Comment: Offer and demand. It is based on how much people are eager to buy or sell either currency, and what they are willing to pay/get for it. In other words, if to morrow a large amount of rupies is needed by someone, and he can’t get it on the market, he will offer higher prices until he gets them; that makes the price go up, etc.. Exactly the same as all currencies, shares, funds, bonds, etc.

Comment: Ok, understood. So, can we predict it somehow, with say 90% chances?

Comment: That’s what million of traders in the world try to do. Feel free to predict the amount of all Rupies people want to buy the next several weeks, and the amount of all Dollars people want to buy the next weeks. If you think one of them is larger than the other, you have an indicator on which direction it moves. Joking aside: unless you are an experienced trader who spends 8 hours a day with the topic, your chances are 0. It’s basically random.

Comment: @Aganju Well, saying your chances are zero is an exaggeration. You could make reasonable predictions if you accept a broad enough margin of error. To take the extreme. I'd be confidant predicting that 1 rupee will be worth more than zero dollars tomorrow. You could look at how the rate has varied in the last few weeks and you'd be pretty safe assuming tomorrow will be in the same general range. You could use knowledge of the relative strength of the Indian and US economies. Etc. The chance that you'll mak a better guess than the professionals who do it every day is probably close to zero.